# android emulator does not play sound on bluetooth headphone in iMac

Tags: android, macos, audio, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

bluetooth headphone connected to iMac(macOS Sierra v 10.12.2) and system audios could be heard from headphone.

but Android Emulator audio not connect to headphone and play sound on iMac speaker.

Even when the voice of the iMac is mute , Emulator sound could be heard from speaker.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

With this way:

1. Open System Preferences
2. Click on Sound
3. Click on "Sound Effects"
4. Set "Play sound effects through" to "Selected sound output device"
5. Set the Alert volume almost at max.
6. in Output Tab , select Bluetooth headphone as output
7. in Input Tab , selecte Internal Microphone as input

The problem will be solved

Comment: Looks like especially setting the input to internal microphone did it for me, thanks!

Comment: I followed this but after opening the emulator had to disconnect and reconnect my bluetooth headphones as well ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: this solution is not working for me, no matter which options i select for output.
In my case i have USBC headphones, which may be the issue.

Comment: @BrillPappin I don't think it's related to your USBC headphones.  Nothing in this selected answer or its comments works for me.  I use AirPods 2.  Nothing will make the emulator audio go to headphones.  I think that either the emulator or MacOS is broken.  This frustrating when developing in a noisy cafe, and I cannot hear the audio feature I'm working on.

Answer (score 24):

Follow the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42482060/android-emulator-not-play-sound-on-bluetooth-headphone-in-imac/42482061#42482061) and if it still didn't help then do a **Cold Boot**:

1. Go to **Tools** > **AVD Manager**
2. Find your virtual device and in the **Actions** section click on the drop down button and select **Cold Boot Now**.

Comment: For me restart to mac and then cold boot helped :D
what a bug... thx tho

Comment: for me connect the headphone first then do emulator cold boot works :)

Answer (score 7):

None of the solutions helped me. I think this is a bug: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/132475237

Answer (score 3):

I had similar problem on MacBook. Sound from Android Emulator wasn't playing in Bluetooth headphones. None of the above solutions worked. Then I tried to add new Audio Device, and finally it worked, however sound plays slightly distorted.

1. Open Audio MIDI Setup
2. Create Device (plus icon in the bottom left corner)
3. Check your output device in the list on the right to use it in Aggregate Device
4. Select the newly created Aggregated Device in Sound Preferences to use it as output
5. Start Android Emulator using Cold Boot

Comment: After so many false leads etc... THIS THIS WAS IT!!!  YOU ARE THE CHAMP!!!

Answer (score 0):

#### If the answers above didn't solve the issue:

I tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42482061/11082758) but it didn't work. I then solved it with the 2 steps below without reverting the settings.

- Change your sound output using `built-in` speaker.
  In my case, use m1 mac-mini.
- Change **bluetooth speaker** to **Mac mini Speakers** then worked.

Also do not forget launch AVD using **Cold Boot** start.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution

1. Start emulator first then connect bluetooth .
2. In systemPreference -> sound -> check sound balane is automaticaly set to left
   [image]

Answer (score -8):

Quick Fix: Try using an actual Android for testing out applications if you can.

Two good reasons to switch to an actual android device for testing:

```
1. Emulator eats up device memory and results would mostly vary on an actual android.
2. Testing on an actual device is a better way of ensuring that the application 
   behaves as expected on the actual device.
```

Sorry about not providing you an actual answer to the asked question, rather an alternative. But when I started programming for android devices, the android emulator would take up a lot of memory and time, due to which I decided to move to an actual android device early(I probably saved a lot of time and frustration in the long run, since I had only 4 GB RAM and Android Studio is quite memory hungry too).

So I generally suggest people to use an actual device(probably a Moto or a Nexus, since they are stock Android Devices) instead of testing on emulators also because of the occasional compatibility issues like your current sound issue.

Good luck either ways :)

Comment: If the question is about making this work in an emulator, then there is probably a reason for that. I'm sure the OP knows how to use an actual device. :-)